# Transport.send is not working

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

While trying to use 
`Transport.send(message, addresses);` or `transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());`
while sending mail using java, the process never ends only when I provide wrong password for my attachment file.

Tried some solutions from below links but does not help:
[Link 1:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35907980/transport-sendmsg-not-working)

[Link 2:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907229/transport-sendmessage-not-working-in-the-below-code-netbeans-gets-stuck-at-t)

Interestingly, process hangs only when I am providing wrong password for the attachment. While it works when I provide correct password for the attachment. Attached file is from SFTP server.
Using gmail SMTP account to send an email:
Server domain: smtp.gmail.com
Port: 465
Secure Connection: SSL

Anyone having any thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: Need more details...  How are you fetching the attachment before attaching it to your mail message?  What line of code does your process hang on?

Comment: process hangs on Transport.send(message, addresses)

Comment: What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?

Comment: where will I get those logs from?

Comment: They're written to System.out.  It depends on where your app is running where that shows up.  If you're running in an application server, there may be a server log file.